# Fetching data from openweather api based on user location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fetch weather data based on user location. Can someone tell me why this is not working? I have tried this since forever. I get the coords correctly, but not able to fetch weather based on them. The error message I get from openweather is "wrong latitude". As if the latitude and longitude never gets to the API request.

```
   
    
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);
   

       
    async function getLocation() {
        let {
            status
        } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') return;

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            maxAge: 36000000,
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest
        })

        let { coords } = location;
        console.log(coords);

        setLatitude(coords.latitude);
        setLongitude(coords.longitude);

        //console.log(location)
    }

    async function getWeatherData() {
        let API = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=metric&appid=**MY-API-KEY**`
        try {
            await fetch(API)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
               

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            
            getLocation()
                .then(() => {
                    if (latitude !== undefined && longitude !== undefined)
                    getWeatherData();

                    console.error('Couldn"t fetch weather data')

                })
                

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }, []);
```

Comment: could you console.log latitude and longitude values before make the API request?

Comment: Yep, they work properly. console.log(coords) include all the necessary data including latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Try passsing latitude and longitude as parameteres.

like this:

```js
   async function getWeatherData(lat, long) {
        let API = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&appid=**MY-API-KEY**`
        try {
            await fetch(API)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
               

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            
            getLocation()
                .then(() => {
                    if (latitude !== undefined && longitude !== undefined) {
                      getWeatherData(latitude, longitude);
                    }
                    console.error('Couldn"t fetch weather data')

                })
                

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }, []);
```

tell me if it is working so I can explain what I think went wrong

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It works with parameters. However, it still sometimes gives me undefined is not an object (evaluating 'main.temp'), which is a property returned from the object that includes the temperature. And when it gives me a location, it points to a place that I'm not even near by. Sometimes London, sometimes Spain, even though the coordinates from the returned location from expo are correct... Why this might be..?

Comment: first of all let me explain the paramteres thing. when sending the lat and long as paramteres you are garanteeing that you  are sending the data you wish to send, other then relaying on a state that you dont know when it is set.

Comment: When it comes to the returned object, you have to check if it is definded before printing it out